# C# Excel file download corrupting file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, httpresponse

I've written some code that downloads a certain file to the user's computer, which is a MS Excel .xlsx file. The problem is that when a user downloads and opens the file from my web app, I get a message in excel saying "We found a problem with some content in file.xlsx." I then click yes to recover the contents and this is what the log file shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error128120_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'F:\Downloads\file.xlsx'</summary><additionalInfo><info>Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.</info></additionalInfo></recoveryLog>
```

This is the code I am using to download the file in C#. From my research I believe this is the correct mimetype for .xlsx. Also when I open the file in the folder explorer, the issue does not appear, **only after download.** I have tried both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

```
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/"), "file.xlsx"));
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "file.xlsx");
        Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sometime it is problem of encoding

```
 var result = new StreamWriter(output);
```

Don't use any specific encoding while writing to output buffer stream

Comment: Bingo on the encoding comment.  Don't specify an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the file is actually not corrupt?

If you are using ASP .NET MVC, why not return a FileResult from your action? I would consider that the standard way of doing it.

*Update*
You can let your controller send a file to the browser for downloading by returning a FileResult from it. Use the File method in a way very similar to the View method inside the controller.

Example:

```
public ActionResult(int id)
{
    var downloadStream = GetSomePdfStream(id);
    //note how I specified the MIME type, so that the browser knows what am I sending to it.
    return File(downloadStream, "application/pdf", "file.pdf"); 
}
```

There are several convenient overloads to return a file from a byte[] or Stream or path:

```
File(Stream stream, string mime, string downloadName) //returns System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult:FileResult
File(string fileName, string mime, string downloadName);//returns FilePathResult:FileResult
File(byte[] contents, string mime, string downloadName);//returns FileContentResult:FileResult
```

Comment: As I said, in file explorer, opening the file naturally gives no errors. Once downloaded through the program, the file has errors. I can mark your answer as correct if you can maybe show me the way with FileResult?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. I enhanced the answer, let me know if it helps.